# Display image in tooltip using materialize css

Tags: css, materialize

I have the following HTML

```
<a href="#" title="" id="preview" class="waves-effect waves-blue btn blue lighten-2">Bunny</a>
```

as well as the following JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#preview").tooltip(
        {
           content: '<img src="bunny.jpg" />'
        }
     );
});
```

However, when I mouse over the button, all I get is a small black 1px x 10px tooltip. I want the tooltip to be an image, but it seems materialize is getting in the way of that.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation you can use option `html`. It can take regular HTML code. https://materializecss.com/tooltips.html

```
<a class="btn tooltipped" data-position="bottom">Hover me!</a>

$('.tooltipped').tooltip({
 html: "<img src='path.png'>"
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4wq1mnx5/9/